# best way to compare items inside a loop

Tags: c#, collections

i have a collection of objects.  i need to loop through the collection and generate another collection.  each item in the second collection is a function of two items in the first collections.  So to simplify the problem.

Lets assume the collection is a set of ints.

```
 List<int> myIntCollection = new List<int>() {1, 4, 6, 8, 7};
```

i need to generate a second collection in which each item is the sum of 2 of the items in the first collection. so the second collection would have these elements after the conversion.

```
 List<int> generatedCollection = new List<int>() {5, 10, 14, 15};
```

as you can see the first element is 5 (which is the sum of the first two items in the top collection), the second elemtn is 10, which is hte sum of the second and third item in the first collection and so on . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
List<int> result = new List<int>(source.Count - 1);

for (int i = 0; i < source.Count - 1; i++)
    result.Add(source[i] + source[i + 1]);
```

<sub>That wasn't hard!</sub>

Comment: Won't that throw an exception on the last one?

Comment: @pete no since he is doing count - 1 in the check.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense but isn't the count - 1 already required?  Are list indexes not zero based?

Comment: @Pete: Your two comments answer one another.

Comment: @Pete He's doing i < count - 1, then if count is 1, it won't run at all because 0 is not less than 0.

Comment: @slaks Thanks.  I was genuinely asking because I'm still fairly novice and more often than not something doesn't work the way I would expect because of some mechanic I don't know or understand fully.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
generatedCollection.AddRange(
            myIntCollection.Where(j => i < myIntCollection.Count - 1).Select(
                j => myIntCollection[i] + myIntCollection[i++ + 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Enumerable.Range` method to create a collection on the fly, and get the sum of two items for each index:

```
List<int> generatedCollection =
  Enumerable.Range(0, myIntCollection.Length - 1)
  .Select(i => myIntCollection[i] + myIntCollection[i + 1])
  .ToList();
```